# Not sure what is happening in this java code example

Tags: java, android, class, methods, overriding

The code example I'm referring to is a bit of Android specific code, but I have a feeling the idea is a fundamental one in Java.  In the code snippet below I am confused by what is happening from the second line on.  It looks like in the setOnClickListener() method a whole new class is being defined.  It looks to me like a method is being defined within the arguments of another method, onClick() being defined inside of setOnClickListener().  This whole thing is very confusing to me as I have never seen Java written like this, except in Android.

Could someone please explain what I am seeing here?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
final Button downButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
downButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Play key click sound
        mAudioManager.playSoundEffect(AudioMAnager.FX_KEY_CLICK);

        if (mVolumne > mVolumeMin) {
            mVolume -= 2;
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(mVolume));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Google anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `setOnClickListener()`, a new class is being defined. It is what is known as an anonymous class. Anonymous classes are used to define quick new types that do something specific and different to each method call, such as an action performed on a click. The anonymous class always implicitly extends the class that the curly braces come off the new instance of the object. To make this easier to understand: `new OnClickListener() {...`, `OnClickListener` is the superclass (or interface) of your new anonymous class.

In your case, `OnClickListener` is an interface, therefore you have to implement the functions defined in that interface into your anonymous class. That implemented method is then called in the function when your action takes place. Java's Swing library makes heavy use of anonymous classes too.

So to answer your question, what is happening is that a new class is being created, that is only used in this method call - the class is not visible (or useable) anywhere else. In summary, anonymous classes allow you to create your own custom types subclassed from the specified class or interface. It allows you to do many things easier, and have specialty within your action.

Comment: So in this example I'm craeting the OnClickListener to do something specific when this button is pressed, correct? If I wanted a bunch of buttons that did the same thing would it make sense to create one OnClickListener beforehand and just pass that one in to each button's setOnClickListener()?

Comment: You got it! Just create a custom inner class, or in a new file, and create a new instance of it.

Answer (score 2):

The code is creating an anonymous inner class. (Thanks, David.) Basically, it's making a new instance of the `OnClickListener` class. This class has a number of methods, including `onClick(View v)`. The class "listens" to see what happens if there is a click, and calls the `onClick` method. However, the method does not do anything. The only way to make it do something is to make a new instance of this class, and define the method as doing something.

Answer (score 1):

when button is clicked onClick() function is called

AudioManager provides access to volume and ringer mode control.

int FX_KEY_CLICK :  Keyboard and direction pad click sound

so this line will play the sound of the key when keyboard key is pressed.

and then the if loop is easy just printing sound value